# animate() nao funciona com href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, tenho um script que é um slideshow de imagens com um `animate()` para o topo. funciona 100%. mas se eu adiciono um `<a href="#">` na imagem. o efeito para. poderiam me ajudar? segue ele funcionando

http://jsfiddle.net/d4n7dcnf/12/

Comment: Pela minha experiência, um `a` em torno de um `img` não assume automaticamente o tamanho do `img`. Mas pode ser outra coisa. Tem um exemplo dele *não* funcionando? (i.e. um exemplo de como você tentou fazer e não deu certo) A propósito, se puder postar o trecho de código mais relevante na pergunta mesmo, em vez de um link externo, seria bom (o link pode acompanhar, ajuda bastante, só seria melhor se não fosse *só* o link).

Comment: Veja [isto](http://jsfiddle.net/d4n7dcnf/17/), tens aí um exemplo não funcionando já com as tags adicionadas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O efeito para pelo seguinte motivo:

HTML com a tag `<a>`:

```
<div>
    <div id="container">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://duvaleimoveis.com.br/admin/dest/thumb.php?img=fotos/3a8d87a624cfd7dc68bcbd1c2d45ebee.jpg"/></a>

      <a href="#"><img src="http://duvaleimoveis.com.br/admin/dest/thumb.php?img=fotos/f15d8f97b154858f411c17ef999ae5ab.jpg"/></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

A tag `<img>` passa a ser `children` de a e a `children` de container e no CSS o a é quem deve estar como position `absolute`, então no CSS linha:

```
#container > img
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

mude para:

```
#container >  a
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

note que seu código continuará funcionando normalmente http://jsfiddle.net/d4n7dcnf/16/

Comment: muito obrigado. nao tinha pensado nisso. vlw

Comment: de nada, não mereço +1 não?